# Perturbative expansion of matrix trace $\mathrm{Tr}((P+R)\log(P+R))$ for $R$ small

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, taylor-expansion

Let $P$ and $R$ be finite-dimensional square matrices. Furthermore, let $P$ be a projection to a 1-dimensional subspace, and suppose that $P+R$ is positive semidefinite. Then, the quantity
$$S = \mathrm{Tr}((P+R)\log(P+R))$$
is well-defined even when $P+R$ is only positive-*semi*definite, under the interpretation $0\log 0 =0$. Suppose further that $R$ is small. Then, can we perturbatively expand as
$$S = \mathrm{Tr}(P\log P) + \mathrm{Tr}(\big(\ldots\big)R) + \mathcal O(R^2) = \mathrm{Tr}(\big(\ldots\big)R) + \mathcal O(R^2),$$
where $\big(\ldots\big)$ is what we want to know?

Let me try the simplest case. Assuming that $P$ and $R$ are $1\times 1$ matrices, i.e., numbers, we may proceed as
$$\log(P+R) = \log P + \log(1+P^{-1}R) = P^{-1}R + \mathcal O(R^2) ,$$
so that
$$S = (P+R) P^{-1}R + \mathcal O(R^2) = R +\mathcal O(R^2).$$
I wonder whether the answer is still $S = \mathrm{Tr}(R) + \mathcal O(R^2)$ for general matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a wonderful theorem for the gradient of the trace of a matrix function
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad} 
\def\p{\partial} 
\def\D{\Delta} 
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}} 
&\phi(X) = {\rm Tr}\big(f(X)\big) \\
&\grad{\phi}{X} = f'(X) \qiq \D \phi = {\rm Tr}\Big(f'(X)\cdot\D X\Big) \\
}$$
where $f'$ is the ordinary scalar derivative.

The scalar function
$$\eqalign{
f(x) &= x\,\log(x) \qiq f'(x) = 1 + \log(x) \\
}$$
can be used to write your function (with $P=X,\:R=\D X,\:S=\phi$)
$$\eqalign{
S &= {\rm Tr}\big(f(P)\big)
  &= {\rm Tr}\big(P\,\log(P)\big) \\
\Delta S &= {\rm Tr}\big(f'(P)\cdot R\big)
  &= {\rm Tr}\big(R+R\cdot\log(P)\big) \\\hline
(S+\Delta S) &= {\rm Tr}\big(R\big) + {\rm Tr}\big((P&+R)\cdot\log(P)\big) \\
}$$